# How do I install Linux on a Mac Mini without Intel

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu, mac, refit

community. Lately I've been installing Ubuntu on my families computers, and have succeeded with the Windows Pc's. But I also wanted to install it on a Mac Mini. The problem is I have a PowerPc core and I need intel for things like rEFIt, Boot Camp Assistant, stuff like that. If theres a way to do that, let me know please.

Comment: It seems that you want dual boot. Ubuntu has some choppy PowerPC builds, choppy, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads#A14.04_Trusty_Tahr. I guess the logic is that nobody would need boot camp with PowerPC because you couldn't install Windows on it in the first place. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1226483?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: A PowerPC-based computer can't dual-boot with an x86 version of Windows, which is what Boot Camp does. Also, rEFIt is an EFI boot manager, but PowerPC-based Macs don't use EFI, so rEFIt will be useless. To dual-boot OS X and Linux on such a computer, you'll use another boot manager, such as Yaboot. It's been a while since I did this, though, so I can't provide you with details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Ubuntu MATE for PowerPC, you can download it [here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-trusty-powerpc/).